# Knife ec2: need to avoid re-boostraping of server after hostname change

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos, chef-infra, hostname, knife

I might be doing something wrong, but here is the situation. Standalone Chef server 12.3.0. CentOS 6.3 running on AWS.
During execution of `knife bootstrap` I am applying [hostname:default](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/hostname) recipe to change server's FQDN along with some other recipes. Everything iseems to be fine. Chef server shows newly boostrapped instance, but **Node Name** column is still showing old FQDN, smth like *ip-x-x-x-x.aws-region-name.compute.internal*.

Then I try to ssh this host and run `chef-client` I am getting following error:

```
[ec2-user@newHostName ~]$ sudo chef-client  
Starting Chef Client, version 12.3.0

Chef encountered an error attempting to load the node data for "newHostName"
Authentication Error:
----------------
Failed to authenticate to the chef server (http 401).

Server Response:
----------------
Failed to authenticate as 'newHostName'. Ensure that your node_name and client key are correct.

Relevant Config Settings:
-------------------------
chef_server_url   "https://chefServerDomain/organizations/organizationName"
node_name         "newHostName"
client_key        "/etc/chef/client.pem"

If these settings are correct, your client_key may be invalid, or
you may have a chef user with the same client name as this node.

[2015-05-04T12:36:03-07:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 0.962848623 seconds
[2015-05-04T12:36:03-07:00] ERROR: 401 "Unauthorized"
[2015-05-04T12:36:03-07:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

I have checked closed issue [#8](https://github.com/3ofcoins/chef-cookbook-hostname/issues/8) on GitHub, according to which I need manually change *client.rb* file and include **node_name** parameter. At the same time Chef client.rb documentation indicates that I should not do that :

> node_name is used to determine which configuration should be applied
>   and to set the client_name    (which is the name used when
>   authenticating to a Chef server). The default value is set
>   automatically to    be the FQDN of the chef-client, as detected by
>   Ohai. In general, leaving this setting blank and letting    Ohai
>   assign the FQDN of the node as the node_name during each chef-client
>   run is the recommended    approach.

After cleaning up **/etc/chef/*** folder, removing this instance from Chef server and re-bootstrapping EC2 instance again I was able to make it work. FQDN was displayed correctly in Chef server under **Node Name** column as *newServerName*.

Could you please advise, what should I do to avoid double bootsrapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass the node name you want the node to use into with "-N hostname" to the bootstrap command. Then it will register properly with the final node name.

Comment: Thank you! In my case following command `knife bootstrap -i mykey.pem xx.xx.xx.xx -N serverName  -r roleName -E envName -x userName --sudo` worked perfectly fine!